# CheckBoxList to be dynamically populated once during page load

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm using visual studio 2010 to code my web part.

I have a `CheckBoxList` which retrieve content from my SharePoint.

```
SPWeb objCurrentWeb;
SPList objStaffList;
objCurrentWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;

//Using SharePoint object model to retrieve both lists
objStaffList = objCurrentWeb.Lists["Staff List"];

foreach (SPListItem objStaffListItem in objStaffList.Items)
{
    staffList.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(objStaffListItem["Name"]));
    break;
}
```

I have another `Button` on this webpart to retrieve the `DateTimeControl`. When ever I press the `Button`, the above list will add duplicate items in my `CheckBoxList`.

How do I make it such a way that it will not add items into `staffList`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` method use `if (!IsPostBack){}`
and write your check box list populating code inside the brackets.